# How to properly time with nested for loops in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, benchmarking

I'm trying to time how long it takes for a client to receive a few messages from another client. When create a single for loop and time the result it gives me a normal result:

```
 // 1 trial sending 10 messages
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {  
        receivedMessage = receivingQueue.receive(MESSAGEWAITTIME,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(); // receives incoming messages as Mqtt5Publish instances  (.get() will return the Mqtt5Publish without the Optional<>)                                                                     
        byte[] tempData = receivedMessage.getPayloadAsBytes();    // converts the Optional<Mqtt5Publish> to a byte array 
        String getData = new String(tempData);  // converts the byte array to a String 
        out.println(getData);  // writes each message as a String to a text file
    }
        out.close();

    endTime = System.nanoTime();
```

The above code gives me an average of 191 milliseconds (I convert it from nano later on in the code) while when I add a nested for loop however my result is actually less and drops down to around 35 milliseconds with the code below. I'm aware of JIT but I have turned it off in the JV arguments in eclipse with the following: `-Djava.compiler=NONE` yet the code still looks like it being optimized by the compiler.

```
// 50 trials sending 10 messages
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {  
                receivedMessage = receivingQueue.receive(MESSAGEWAITTIME,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(); // receives incoming messages as Mqtt5Publish instances  (.get() will return the Mqtt5Publish without the Optional<>)                                                                     
                byte[] tempData = receivedMessage.getPayloadAsBytes();    // converts the Optional<Mqtt5Publish> to a byte array 
                String getData = new String(tempData);  // converts the byte array to a String 
                out.println(getData);  // writes each message as a String to a text file
            }
                out.close();

            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            timeReceive = endTime - startTime; 
            timeReceiveTotal = timeReceive + timeReceiveTotal;
        }
            timeReceiveTotal = timeReceiveTotal/50;  // gets the average of 50 trials
    }
```

Comment: It is possible that "receivingClient1" takes some time to initialize as it seems to be going over the network as it is setting up the connections. But once the connection is established, the subsequent calls are faster.
It will be great if you can separately time different statement in nested for loop to see which one is becoming faster.

Comment: @AbhishekGarg I should have mentioned that receivingClient 1 is a "Resource which queues incoming messages until they are received" and is not actually a client. The `.receive()` actually retrieves the method and the `.get()` just removes an Optional from the variable (a Mqtt5Publishes instance). I updated the post with the renamed variable.